# Problema con subreporte en ireport

Tags: ireport

Estoy trabajando con ireport y me ha tocado incluir un subreporte a mi reporte principal...me costó hacerlo funcionar puesto que no estoy usando base de datos, por lo tanto, al final se solucionó indicando que use un datasource vacío al momento de insertarlo en el informe principal(adjunto imagen)
[image: Configuración de subreporte]

Ahora que ya tengo el subreporte funcionando se me presenta el problema de que me muestra solo un registro, es decir, no itera el detalle....alguna idea de que estará faltando????